# Outlook Choose Profile Once-Off

Tags: microsoft-outlook, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there a way to get Outlook to only ask to choose profile as a once-off every now and then?

Currently I would go into Control Panel and change the setting to ask at boot and then turn it off when I'm not going to require that feature (usually 2-3 days at end of month).

Can I do this as a once-off every now and then either with a Desktop shortcut to select a particular profile or hold down a key (eg - <kbd>CTRL</kbd>) when opening Outlook to prompt it to ask me only that boot time?

---

**More Info:** This is the window that I am referring to, in Control Panel under the *Mail (32-bit)* snap-in

[image]

I want to be able to trigger Outlook to ask me which profile to use, without having to go into the Control Panel and change the radio button to `Prompt for a profile to be used`. I want it to prompt me using a shortcut or by holding a button whilst launching Outlook. Normally, it always loads just my *Outlook* profile. (26 days of each month I only use the Outlook profile).

Comment: I use outlook daily and I have no idea what your talking about please clarify

Comment: Added more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create three separate shortcuts for starting Outlook? Use the /profile command  line argument, like this:

```
outlook /profile profilename
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old post but I use this feature from time to time and surprisingly I've not been able to (easily) find documentation regarding this for any version of Office honestly and this page is the first result I came across when searching Google to remember the key combination.

**As of Outlook 2013 and 2016 you're able to achieve this using the SHIFT button when opening your first Outlook instance.** If Outlook is already open then this will open a second window using the current profile. This will not work on Outlook 2010.